# Intersection of Submodules inside a Tensor Product

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R \subset S$ a flat, injective extension of commutative rings, $M \subset N $ an inclusion of $R$-modules. We identify $M \otimes_S 1_R \subset  N \otimes_R 1_S \subset N \otimes S$ as $R$-submodules.

**Question:** Is there an immediate argument to show that $M \otimes_R 1_S = (N \otimes_R 1_S) \cap M \otimes_R S $?

Note, that if $R$ would be a field, then $N \otimes S$ would have a basis consisting of $\{s_i \otimes n_j \}$, where $\{s_i\}_{i \in I}$ form basis of $S$ over $R$, where $\{n_i\}_{j \in J}$ is $R$-basis of $N$ and we could make a coefficient comparison argument for an element from $(N \otimes_R 1_S) \cap M \otimes_R S $.

But for general $R$ and modules $M,N$ such argument using basis decomposition not works due to absence of well defined bases. How to prove the claim else? Is it at all true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false in general. Here's a counterexample: $R = \mathbb{Z}$, $M = \mathbb{Z}$, $N = \mathbb{Q}$, $S = \mathbb{Q}$. However, what you mentioned is true if $R \subset S$ is *faithfully flat*. Indeed, the below commutative diagram has the top row being exact. The flatness of $S$ tells you that the bottom row is also exact. Moreover, the vertical tensor maps are also injective because of the stronger assumption of faithful flatness. Now, what you want to show is that if something in $N \otimes_R S$ comes from both $N$ and $M \otimes_R S$, then it in fact comes from $M$. Indeed, this is clear from exactness and diagram chasing.

[image]

Comment: Nice! Do you know if this can be sharpen? Namely, you showed that if $R \to S$ is faithfully flat, then $M \otimes_R 1_S = (N \otimes_R 1_S) \cap M \otimes_R S$ holds. But one might also ask the converse question if this gives in turn a sufficient criterion for faithfully flatness: If for every inclusion $M \subset N$ of $R$ - modules holds $M \otimes_R 1_S = (N \otimes_R 1_S) \cap M \otimes_R S$, then $R \to S$ is faithfully flat? Or is it too optimistic?