# A Criterion for Faithfully Flatness via Intersection Property

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $R \subset S$ be an injective map of commutative rings, $M \subset N $ an inclusion of $R$-modules. We identify $M, N$ respectively as $M \otimes_R 1_S \subset  N \otimes_R 1_S \subset N \otimes S$.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4880014) Haran elaborated that if $R \subset S$  a faithfully flat extension, then the intersection of  $N \otimes_R 1_S $ and $ M \otimes_R S $ behaves as nice as one would naive expect, i.e.,  $$M \otimes_R 1_S = (N \otimes_R 1_S) \cap M \otimes_R S. $$

**Remark:** As Aphelli pointed out, the intersection inside $N \otimes_R S $ with $M \otimes_R S $ should be read as the intersection with **the image of** the induced map  $M \otimes S \to N \otimes S $, which (if we not assume flatness for $\phi$ not need to be injective)

**Question:** What about a converse statement? Can this be used as sufficient criterion for faithfully flatness? (at least if we already assume $R \subset S$ to be flat?)

That means, if for all inclusions $M \subset N $ of $R$-modules,  holds $M \otimes_R 1_S = (N \otimes_R 1_S) \cap M \otimes_R S $, then does it follow that $R \subset S$ is faithfully flat?

Comment: If you don’t already assume that $M \otimes_R S$ is a submodule of $N \otimes_R S$, how do you define this intersection? Or do you mean “those elements in $N \otimes_R 1_S$ that are in the image of $M \otimes_R S$”?

Comment: @Aphelli: Thanks, that should be clarified. If I assume $R \to S$ to be flat, then there should not appear such kind of problem. If flatness is not going to be assumed, then I define the intersection exactly as you said, as intersection with the image (set theoretically) of induced map $M \otimes S \to N \otimes S $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $R\to S$ is injective and flat, the answer is yes:

Let $M\subset R$ be an ideal and let $N=R$. Then from the assumption we get that $M\otimes_R1_S=R\otimes_R1_S\cap M\otimes_RS\subset R\otimes_RS$. Via the obvious identifications, this becomes $M=R\cap MS\subset S$. Thus, if $MS=S$, then $M=R$. Since $M$ was arbitrary (and under the assumption that $S/R$ is flat to begin with), it follows that $S/R$ is faithfully flat.